# Difference in SQL for sequence in db2 for Hibernate 4 and 5

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, db2

Is there a way I can manage or change the Hibernate 5 generated sql for how the sequence is retrived from AS400 DB2? Or revert it to use the Hibernate 4 SQL?

I have a Entity mapped as follows:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "D")
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "art_id_gen",
        sequenceName = "G_ID_SEQ",
        allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "art_id_gen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;
```

When I use Hibernate 4 the SQL is (which works):

```
values nextval for G_ID_SEQ;
```

but when ussing Hibernate 5 the SQL is (which doesn't work):

```
select next_val as id_val from G_ID_SEQ for update with rs;
```

I'm using the
    org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect

Anyone have some input or suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: What dialect are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

which is generating the same sql as hibernate 4:

```
values
    nextval for G_ID_SEQ
```

---

One year later I stumbled on this in my code and eventually we patched the DB2400Dialect:

```
/**
 * This is a patched version of the PatchedDB2400Dialect which is working in hibernate 5 and DB2 AS400
 *
 * There seems to be a problem with generated SQL for sequences and tables generated SQL for increment of unique id's
 * and identities. Either the sequence work when using DB2Dialect and not table generators or vice versa for DB2400Dialect.
**/
public class PatchedDB2400Dialect extends DB2400Dialect {
        private static final LimitHandler LIMIT_HANDLER = new AbstractLimitHandler() {
            @Override
            public String processSql(String sql, RowSelection selection) {
                if ( LimitHelper.hasFirstRow( selection ) ) {
                    //nest the main query in an outer select
                    return "select * from ( select inner2_.*, rownumber() over(order by order of inner2_) as rownumber_ from ( "
                            + sql + " fetch first " + getMaxOrLimit( selection ) + " rows only ) as inner2_ ) as inner1_ where rownumber_ > "
                            + selection.getFirstRow() + " order by rownumber_";
                }
                return sql + " fetch first " + getMaxOrLimit( selection ) + " rows only";
            }
...
```

Comment: `org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect` might be even more appropriate and save you some headaches in the more exotic cases.

Comment: Interesting that a more general dialect works better than a more specific. Smells like a bug.

Comment: Interesting that Hibernate still requires users to specify the dialect and not auto-detect it from the JDBC driver and database, when other JPA providers do it automatically by default